# How to disable the esc key , F11, and popup from exiting fullscreen mode in php?

Tags: javascript, php

How to disable the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in the keyboard from exiting the fullscreen mode in a page? Also how to disable the <kbd>F11</kbd> key and also remove the popup message showing "exit fullscreen"?

Actually i m doing a online bank examination. When a candidate is writing an exam, he should not be able to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, click on the popup, or press <kbd>F11</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP your aren't able to control any client side key events. Check the javascript events for keyup, keypress and keydown events and keyCodes.

Examples: 
http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/Extras-Javascript-Keycodes.html
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp